# Listbox selection wrong when an item is inserted twice

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox

I have two listboxes which I both bind to the same selected index. The reason for this is that in the first one I enter some things and then specify to which property it belongs:

For example:

- Bird
- Dog
- Fish

Can be combined with

- House
- Garder
- Living room

Everything works fine when each item occurres only once but when I have something like

- Dog House
- Fish House

Then the synchronization isn't working.
I have tried `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` but this gave me an exception when I opened the page.

This is the code for the listboxes

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListBoxItem,Mode=TwoWay}" 
         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}"/>
<ListBox BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Places}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}"/>
```

Just to not cause some confusion about the datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="15"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

EDIT:
When I want to set it to true I see in the designer the following message

`[Selector_IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemCannotSetToTrue]
Arguments:
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient ....`

The number of items in both listboxes is always the same.

The exception (web page error) is the generic

`Line: 1
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`

Comment: "but this gave me an exception" - what exception? stacktrace?

Comment: Is the _number_ of items always equal in both lists?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes... you first add an "animal" from the treeview and after that you add a "place" from another treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding always the same item from the treeview I create a new from the selected item which is then passed into the listbox. This way you have to different items but at the end I only care about their Id (placeID) so that it doesn't matter...

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem on windows phone 7.1. The internal exception was somephing like: setting IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to true is not supported